# AWS: Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'numpy'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gitlab, serverless-framework, serverless

**AWS Newbie here**

I have to host my python scripts via gitlab CI as a lambda and trigger it by cloudwatch on AWS.

I am following the following tutorials:

1. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/clusters/serverless/aws.html
2. https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/

From the first tutorial, I am taking just the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and adding it to the tutorial shown in the second tutorial (but  instead of python 3.6, I am choosing 3.7 as the runtime)

I have the following `serverless.yml` file

```
service: numpy-test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.7

functions:
  numpy:
    handler: handler.main

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux

package:
  exclude:
    - venv/**
```

and the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
image: node:latest

stages:
  - deploy

production:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - npm config set prefix /usr/local
    - npm install -g serverless
    - npm install --save serverless-python-requirements
  script:
    - serverless deploy
  environment: production
```

When I push the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, it runs without any errors.

[image]

I can see the lambda function created in my AWS lambda. When I connect this lambda with the Cloudwatch so that the lambda gets triggered every 1 minute, I get the following error in the Logs:

[image]

I also have a `requirements.txt` file and it has

```
numpy==1.18.2
```

I have the following files/folders in my directory:
[image]

Can someone please help me out with this and explain me the mistake I am doing and how can it be corrected?

**Edit 1**

I edited the `serverless.yml` file as pointed out by makozaki, and now when I push it in the repo, the CI file fails giving the following error:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the reason could be docker image you have used in .`gitlab-ci.yml` file.
But you want to deploy python lambda with some modules.
Try to use image which has both configuration python as well node like this image:

`nikolaik/python-nodejs`

or if you want some specific version then you can do this also:

```
nikolaik/python-nodejs:python3.7-nodejs13
```

after you got error , i tried to replicate it in my account. 
so, now  i made some changes in serverless.yml as well in .gitlab-ci.yml file here.

you can change service name in serverless.yml
[image]

and aws region in .gitlab-ci.yml 
[image]

after this it deployed in my account and worked fine.
[image]

and here is the test result : 
[image]
Null is there because function is not returning any value but it printed the array.

here is my cloudwatch log: 
[image]

Hope after these changes you will able to make it working.

Comment: i tried to replicate the problem and it is working fine for me, so I'm updating(editing) my result in answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you missed step about adding `serverless-python-requirements` plugin to `serverless.yml`.

Try adding it as mentioned blog:

```yaml
# serverless.yml

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements

custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing it out. After adding it, I get a new error while doing the `serverless deploy`. i am editing the question to add the error

Comment: How about adding also to `.gitlab-ci.yml` before script `npm install --save serverless-python-requirements`

Comment: I did that too, and still I am getting the same error as shown in the edit 1

Comment: So now error log suggests there is some problem with your `package.json`, can you add it's content to question? Did you try executing these commands locally? You don't need to test it via CI.